# Setting RRD deletion granularity

Tags: rrdtool, munin

We currently use RRDtool through munin for trending of our services. We'd like to keep more data than we currently do, that is, we don't want the interstitial points deleted once we get the data gets older than a week. I can't find a flag that I can pass to RRDtool to do this.

We're aware that this will increase the storage requirements, but we'd like to make the decision as to how much data is too much, rather than have it made for us.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rrdtool resize to modify the length of the RRAs